# Proxyquire not stubbing my required class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, es6-class, proxyquire

I have a class `AProvider` that requires `'./b.provider'`.

```
const BProvider = require('./b.provider');

class AProvider {
  static get defaultPath() {
    return `defaults/a/${BProvider.getThing()}`;
  }
}

module.exports = AProvider;
```

`b.provider.js` is adjacent to `a.provider.js` and looks like

```
global.stuff.whatever = require('../models').get('Whatever'); // I didn't write this!

class BProvider {
  static getThing() {
    return 'some-computed-thing';
  }
}
module.exports = BProvider;
```

In my test I use `proxyquire` to mock out `./b.provider` as follows:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

describe('A Provider', () => {
  const Provider = proxyquire('../src/a.provider', {
    './b.provider': {
      getThing: () => 'b-thing'
    },
  });

  describe('defaultPath', () => {
    it('has the expected value', () => {
      expect(Provider.defaultPath).to.equal('defaults/a/b-thing')
    });
  });
});
```

However when I run the test `BProvider` is still requiring the actual `'./b.provider'` not the stub and BProvider's reference to `global.stuff.whatever` is throwing an error.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the proxyquire directive in a `before` statement? Also, not sure if this would help, but this article seems to think using sinon alongside it is necessary: http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/instructing-proxyquire-to-ignore-nested-requires

Comment: Interesting link. I didn't realise the Require still happened despite proxyquire. In a taxi right now but will test a solution when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I have worked out the problem and have found an easy solution which I will post below. Thanks @francisco.preller for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried the post by @Dave Sag and it did not work... however, I found that if I require proxyquire like this ```const proxyquire = require("proxyquire").noCallThru();``` all is good!

Comment: @francisco.preller Hi wanted to read that article, but the link is dead. Can you repoint, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer as to why this is happening is as follows

`proxyquire` still requires the underlying code before stubbing it out. It does this to enable callthroughs.

The solution is simply to *explicitly disallow* callthroughs.

The test becomes:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

describe('A Provider', () => {
  const Provider = proxyquire('../src/a.provider', {
    './b.provider': {
      getThing: () => 'b-thing',
      '@noCallThru': true
    },
  });

  describe('defaultPath', () => {
    it('has the expected value', () => {
      expect(Provider.defaultPath).to.equal('defaults/a/b-thing')
    });
  });
});
```

Running this test works perfectly.